# JS location load after function - Add delay time

Tags: javascript, php

I have made a function.php and I included a redirect (to another page) after processing the function.

It works great - I click / function executes and it redirects.

**BUT**

*I want it not to instant redirect and to delay a couple of seconds*, since I have a message "Succesuful added.. "

**Last part it includes the JS:**

```
//Display ID
    echo "<div align='center'> <h4>*Command completed! NR: ".$id_receptie. </h4></div>";
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload = function () { top.location.href = 'fisa_service.php?id=" . $id_receptie . "'; };
</script>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `setTimeout` function.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  // redirect
}, 2000);
```

The `2000` are the seconds in milliseconds.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! This helped! Works great

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sleep()` function in PHP : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.sleep.php

Comment: <code> echo "<div align='center'> <h4><font color='#10c469'>*Receptie realizata cu success! NR: ".$id_receptie." </font></h4></div>";
 echo "<?php sleep(10); ?>";
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload = function () { top.location.href = 'fisa_service.php?id=" . $id_receptie . "'; }; 

</script>"; </code> does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Try next script:

```
<?php

$timeout = 2;   // Timeout in the seconds
$id_receptie = 0;

?>
<div align='center'><h4>*Command completed! NR: <?= $id_receptie ?> </h4></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    setTimeout(function() {
        top.location.href = 'fisa_service.php?id=<?= $id_receptie ?>';
    }, <?= $timeout ?>*1000);
</script>
<?php

exit;
```